# Difference between SVM and sinusoidal PWM in BLDC

Tags: pwm, brushless-dc-motor, vector-control, sinusoidal

In this answer [Answer to question regarding difference between 6-step and FOC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/329854/75929), the author said:

"Likewise if you have gone to the effort to implement a FOC you might as well implement a SVM block to maximise the utilisation of your DClink voltage (sinusoidal PWM is only 50%, SVM is 86%)".

What i fail to understand is, how is SVM different from sinusoidal PWM. I thought SVM is just sinusoidal PWM on all 3 phases.

What is the difference between SVM and sinusoidal PWM when used with BLDC motors , and how does SVM utilise the DCLink voltage better?

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, I think it's because SPWM kind of treats all three phases independently while SVPWM takes into account all three phases simultaneously. For example, you can do SPWM with just one phase. SVPWM only works with three phases (or maybe more). It doesn't make sense with just one phase

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A BLDC machine is part of the PMSM family. From a machine perspective a BLDC machine will produce higher torque and also higher efficiencies at the expense of higher torque ripple (the commutation dips are large!).

*NOTE: IPM and PMSRM push the efficiency and performance higher for PMSM topologies. These are excited with sinusoidal waveforms

Since BLAC and BLDC machines are PMSM you can excite either with either methods (BLAC with quazi-squarewave and BLDC with sinusoidal). You will gain some of the benefits with crossing their drive topology but not equally when compared to a machine (for the same framesize) optimised for the specific backEMF profile

> How is SVM different from sinusoidal PWM. I thought SVM is just
>   sinusoidal PWM on all 3 phases.
>   What is the difference between SVM and sinusoidal PWM **when used with
>   BLDC motors** , and how does SVM utilise the DCLink voltage better?

I am highlighting that one part specifically because of the opening paragraphs. How you generate the PWM is agnostic to the type of motor being used. "when used with BLDC motors" is a red herring.

Sinusoidal PWM and SVPWM both produce sinusoidal currents,both compare a reference voltage signal to a triangular carrier (for PWM generation). The difference is in how they produce this. The key difference is: SPWM operates on a per-phase basis independently while SVPWM works on all three at once.

Both start off with a sinusoidal phase demand reference (either due to the output of an inverse Clarke-Park transform or via some other source)
[image]

This is where there is a divergence in methods. For S-PWM, these references are directly compared to the triangular carrier. As a result it can only ever produce an output phase voltage that of 0.5Vdc (when compared to the neutral of the motor) because the inverter will switch about a virtual midpoint.

[image]

Even if you were to include a single DCLink capacitor, the "virtual midpoint" would be that of the neutral and equally the star of the motor is a "virtual midpoint". SPWM can therefore only produce +0.5Vdc and -0.5Vdc. At some point you will run out of voltage, voltage needed to push current into the machine.

So how is SVPWM different?  Well because it works on the 3-phase vectors as a whole and tries to synthesis all at once (rather than independently), the resultant voltage waveforms are different. How these are generated (the exact timing, the resultant line-line, the mathematical equations) are an implementation specific point but the result are voltage demands seen below. These are directly compared with the triangle wave carrier to create the needed PWM

[image]

So what is so special about these voltage waveforms?  Their shape presents a root-locus which utilises more of the available DC-link. but how?  The common mode voltage swing

[image]

As mentioned previously, S-PWM is centred around the midpoint of the DClink, with SVPWM, this midpoint moves (due to the dips, the same dips if 3rd harmonic injection was used). Because there is a resultant shift in the CM-voltage, a higher potential difference can be used on a cycle-by-cycle basis, thus extending the potential voltage available to generate line-line voltages.

[image]

[image]

The downside is the starpoint of your motor now has a common-mode component, which causes some serious considerations when you are dealing with EMI.

Finally the reason I stated **Likewise if you have gone to the effort to implement a FOC you might as well implement a SVM block to maximise the utilisation of your DClink voltage** was the beauty of quazi-squarewave control is it is simple. If you are wanting to go the route of FOC, this will produce sinus outputs with a fair amount of computational overhead. A systematic decision must have been made to utilise FOC (performance possibly) and thus to utilise SVPWM is a tiny additional computational overhead ontop of FOC

--edit--
Adding visual overlay of the reference voltage waveforms for

1. Sinusoidal
2. SV-PWM
3. 3rd harmonic injection

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Is there an efficiency difference between SVM and S-PWM, or is it just utilizing the DC-LINK voltage better?
Excellent answer BTW, Thanks

Comment: Oh, that is what this is about. I totally didn't understand the question. Thanks for the nice answer.

Comment: @AhmedEshra higher output voltage will result in lower current for the same operating point when compared to using SPWM. This will result in higher efficiency due to reduction in copper losses. Likewise higher available voltage means higher operating velocities and thus lower losses due to reduction in copper losses.

Comment: So SVM is S-PWM with 3rd harmonic injection?

Comment: At a place I worked when the FW engineer went from six step commutation to SV-PWM, we lost a tiny bit of top-speed. In our application we had hall sensors. By adding speed and throttle dependent phase advance we were able to regain the top speed compared to 6-step. The acoustic noise produced by the motor was a night-and-day difference. Our PWM carrier frequency was above the audible range. We did not do field-oriented control. We just used basically lookup tables on throttle and speed to determine phase advance. The advance was determined empirically.

Comment: no, SVM is a method to realise 3phase voltages based upon utilising three switching combinations for a given sector. By varying the on-time any voltage (on average) can be realised. The resultant voltage waveforms are extremely comparable to that of 3rd harmonic injection (3rd harmonic injection was conceived to improve SPWM before SVPWM & uP were powerful enough to create it)

Comment: I think the SVM mentioned in most blog posts and open source firmware is S-PWM and just labeled incorrectly. https://www.switchcraft.org/learning/2017/3/15/space-vector-pwm-intro. I think the SVM mentioned in this post is actually S-PWM

Comment: @AhmedEshra I have just added a plot for the three main methods (spwm,svpwm,3rd-harmonic) so you can see the difference. As I said 3rd is an old scheme now but was simple to create in analogue.  The blog you posted is SVPWM and captures the sectors. I can't comment on most but if they are anything like blog posts on FOC ... then they could be wrong. The key with svpwm is once you determine what sector you are in and what voltage you want, you cycle through the four valid pwm states to create the desired vector length.

Comment: In the blog post, he mentions adding third harmonic injection to SVM, is that possible?
Also, Where do you recommend i learn about SVM and FOC, any books or easy research papers to understand?

Comment: they don't mention 3rd harmonic with SVM, they mention 3rd harmonic as an alternative to SVM. Its viable if you do not have a floating neutral load. As to references or papers. I have some locally stored for those moments when I have self-doubt. let me find the online links for a few

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping :)