# SVPWM: space vector generation star point shifting - effects?

Tags: common-mode, neutral, vector-control

I keep seeing that the space vector generation (as a part of a FOC) is generated around DC Link / 2. What effects would be expected if the (in this case isolated) star point were **permanently** shifted?

When I search for it, I keep coming across the keyword "common mode voltage", but I still cannot conclusively understand the effects when dealing with an isolated star point.

I am aware of various literature that describes the generation of space vectors, but unfortunately I do not find any information about a permanent shift in the generation from the center (center means 50% duty cycle).

In the typical case, all FETs switch at 50% when the motor is at a standstill and thus brings the star point of the 3-phase system to DC Link / 2.

My question therefore has more of a theoretical background as to whether negative effects would be expected in the event of a permanent displacement from the center (DC Link / 2). In this case, should capacitive equalizing currents be expected (assuming an isolated star Point )? Something like that?

I am very grateful for brief feedback from an expert.

Comment: Much more detail is needed.

Comment: Premature clipping above a certain modulation depth.

Comment: I disagree that there isn't enough information so I do wonder why the question is closed. @ben5en,  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/501397/difference-between-svm-and-sinusoidal-pwm-in-bldc/501451#501451  You are describing two issues 1) CM impact due to SVPWM - the star will "walk" and thus there is a CM perturbation that will cause an EMI consideration.  2) Biased star. If the DCL is derived from rectified AC then star is ~neutral. if it is a 0-DCL then the star will naturally float to half DCL. problem ? no as long as there is suitable voltage withstand